# How to create Google Form Quiz using Google Apps Script or GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

Is it possible to create a quiz form using GAS from a list of questions and answers on the spreadsheet?
I'm making a word test for English learners, on which test-takers are asked to type an answer for each question. 
I've created a quiz with multiple questions or with radio buttons..., but I have been not able to import TEXT answers from spreadsheets to the TEXT-type quiz.

The script I have is below...

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
 var data = range.getValues();
 var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
 var numberColumns = range.getNumColumns();
 var firstRow = 1;
 var form = FormApp.openById('');

 for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){
  var questionType = data[i][0]; 
  if (questionType==''){
     continue;
  }
  else if(questionType=='TEXT'){
   form.addTextItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2])
     .setRequired(true);
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about `I have been not able to import TEXT answers from spreadsheets to the TEXT-type quiz.`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I can create a quiz-form from a spreadsheet with questions ( and answer keys) using Google Apps Script (GAS), but I don't know how to set the answers ( item in form) and points for the correct answer on the form.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that providing your script will help users think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: You are right. I added my script above. Hope it can help other users. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get a look on documentation [sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms)
2. Once you understand how does it work, start by adding [addTextItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addtextitem)
3. Adapt it to your sheet/needs

**Example:**

- I have this list of questions on column A:

[image]

- And now I want to convert these questions into this form:

[image]

- Source code which you should adapt to your needs:

```
function convertToForm(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const questionList = ss.getRange("A1:A7").getValues();

  const form = FormApp.create('New Form');

  questionList.forEach( (question) => { 
    const item = form.addTextItem();
    item.setTitle(question[0])
  })

  // press Ctrl+Enter to see form urls
  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());

}
```

**Reference:**

- [Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms)
- [addTextItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addtextitem)

Comment: @Jescanellas posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629776/how-to-set-correct-answer-text-in-google-forms-from-spreadsheet-using-script that there is an open issue. If this is as important to you as it is to other teachers, please go star it. https://issuetracker.google.com/117437423

Answer (score 1):

I was ecstatic when Google finally let this happen with GAS. Check out [this Google blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/create-quizzes-in-google-forms-with) about creating a quiz using GAS. The scripting for the individual questions is shown below.

```
  // Make a 10 point question and set feedback on it
  var item = FormApp.getActiveForm().addCheckboxItem();
  item.setTitle("What flavors are in neapolitan ice cream?");
  item.setPoints(10);
  // chocolate, vanilla, and strawberry are the correct answers
  item.setChoices([
    item.createChoice("chocolate", true),
    item.createChoice("vanilla", true),
    item.createChoice("rum raisin", false),
    item.createChoice("strawberry", true),
    item.createChoice("mint", false)
  ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However, the quiz I'm making requires "short-answer", which doesn't include multiple-choice or radio-button- kind of things. I just added the script I have onto my query part to refer to. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Google has added the ability to setAnswerKey. The only work-around I can think of would be to turn on manual grade review, create a column in the forms sheet with the "answer key" items, add a script to the form sheet on submit to get the last response every time someone submits, then manually check those responses against the answer key column and change the score for that response item using [``form.getResponse().getResponseForItem().setScore(score);``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#setscorescore). Bit convoluted, but can be done

Comment: @Jescanellas posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629776/how-to-set-correct-answer-text-in-google-forms-from-spreadsheet-using-script that there is an open issue. If this is as important to you as it is to other teachers, please go star it. https://issuetracker.google.com/117437423

Comment: I teach - this would be incredibly useful. We also need to set ALL the settings for forms from the script. It would be nice to give a name to the sheet that holds responses - perhaps the name of the form not just Form Response and a sequential number.  Going in to the form, setting the settings and renaming the response sheet takes time and time is in very short supply.