# Prefill Questions on a Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I know how to prefill a Google form with answers/responses that are populated on a Google Sheet,

I wondered if there is a way to do this in reverse, so prefil a Google Form with not only the answers/responses but also the questions?

For example. Create a hyperlink form which populates Q1,Q3,Q5,Q6 and the response aligned, excluding Q2,Q4,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10 from the form as they are blank

Appreciate any help on this

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please share links to what you have tried already.

Comment: Please see above @RachelMcGuigan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that by creating a Google Form programmatically using Apps Script. You can use [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class for reading/manipulating the sheet and [FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app) class to create and manipulate the Google Form.

You'd first need to get the values from the sheet using for example [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues):

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getValues();
```

And use those value to create the form using the [create()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#createtitle) method:

```
var form = FormApp.create('Form Name');
```

Then you'll have a [Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) object to which you can add question items depending on each question type you wish.

You can guide yourself from this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60656391/11352221) as well.

Comment: Thank you for this... is there a way to populate the forms hyperlink destination in the sheet @AndresDuarte

Comment: What do you mean by form hyperlink destination? You can get the url/link to answer the form with the [getPublishedUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getpublishedurl) method, is that what you mean?