# How to set correct answer text in google forms from spreadsheet using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-form-quiz

I want to make auto-grading short-answer quiz using google forms.

The data is in spreadsheet.

- column A has questions.
- column B has correct answers.
- column C has explanations.

The code below makes quiz, but don't set correct answer in each question.

"item.createResponse(an);" seems not working.

How do I set correct answer?

```js
let form = FormApp.openById(formID);
form.setIsQuiz(true);

// get data from sheet
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('문제');
let range = ss.getDataRange();
let data = range.getValues()

data.forEach(function(el){

    // data
    let qu = el[0];                       //question
    let an = el[1].trim().toUpperCase();  //correct answer
    let ex = el[2];                       //explanation

    // create each question
    let item = form.addTextItem();
    item.setPoints(1);
    item.setTitle(qu);

    // create correct answer
    item.createResponse(an);

    // create explanation
    let exp = FormApp.createFeedback().setText(ex).build();
    if(ex != '') {
      item.setGeneralFeedback(exp);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set correct answers for [Text items](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item) using the Apps Script. It's only possible from the user interface.

It has been requested on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/117437423). You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the request.

Comment: When this finally gets fixed (Thanks @Jescanellas) I want to build forms from my response spreadsheet! This will save me SOOOO much time as a teacher.